# How to read Windows Service configuration while starting the Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am not able to read the `appSettings` from the config file (`MyService.exe.config`) of my Windows Service. Please note that service is installed successfully.

```
  [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public class MyService : ServiceBase
        {

            public MyService()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                ServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceName");
            }

            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                try
                {
                                    AutoLog = true;
                    CanStop = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                                  // Log error
                }
            }

            static void Main()
            {

                        MyService myService = new MyService ();
                        Run(myService);               
            }

                    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                // Code to do necessary things on start
            }
    }
```

The exception in the event viewer is `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException`

**Which is the correct location to read the configuration of the Windows Service?** `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` returns `null` always.

Comment: I have an existing service and this should work: ServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"]; I assume you have checked that the config file was installed in the service directory?

Comment: The code as it is worked perfectly since the problem was in the config file. `appSettings` section was in the wrong place. See ChrisDickson's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception suggests that there is something wrong with your configuration file. Check it carefully. There should be more information in the exception or its inner exception which will give you a more precise indication of what's wrong.

Comment: I have some custom `configSections`. When my `appSettings` section is at the end of the config file, everything works fine! But when it's at the beginning, before `configSections', it throws the error. I am still investigating. But do you know if any particular order is supposed to be followed, by any chance ?

Comment: @CSharpLearner: `configSections` has to come first. The config file schema is documented somewhere on MSDN, though not all that straightforward to find.

Comment: Accepting your response as the answer. You correctly identified that the problem would be with the config file itself. The code as it works fine once config file is fixed.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: You're keeping me in suspense for my little green tick :-) ... glad I helped you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `Settings` instead, and access via `Properties.Settings`.

Check out [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/settings-visual-studio) for more information on doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Windows services will be hosted in `svchost.exe`. So the exe name will be different hence it will not be able to load the config created by .NET. You can

- try putting a `svchost.exe.config` and see if .NET loads the config
- Use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to open a specific config file and read values

Comment: -1 Reference to `svchost.exe` isn't correct. When you use `ServiceBase` you usually host your service in your own process, as the OP has clearly done (MyService.exe).